# Characteristic Function Inequality

Tags: probability

I'm working through some problems in Papoulis and Pillai 4th edition. I'm stuck on understanding what this means

5-46 Show that if $\Phi(\omega) = E\{e^{jwx}\}$ then for any $a_i$,

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \Phi(\omega_i - \omega_k)a_i a_k^* \geq 0.
\end{equation}

Hint:

\begin{equation}
E\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left|a_i e^{j\omega_i x}\right|^2 \right\} \geq 0.
\end{equation}

What does this hint mean? I guess I need to expand that square out to be something. Is this some case of the Biename inequality?

Comment: Your notations are messsed up. $j$ has two meanings.

Comment: Agreed, notation is directly from Papoulis and Pillai. Terrible, yes. I can edit to fix what I think it should be.

Comment: I think the square should be on the summation not the inside. The above summation is just $\sum_k |a_k|^2$.

Answer (score 2):

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \Phi(\omega_i - \omega_k)a_i a_k^{*}=E(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_ie^{j\omega_i x})(\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_ke^{j\omega_k x})^{*}$ and $zz^{*}=|z|^{2}$ for any complex number $z$.